# Find largest continuous sum such that the minimum of it and it's complement is largest

Tags: algorithm

I'm given a sequence of numbers `a_1,a_2,...,a_n`. It's sum is `S=a_1+a_2+...+a_n` and I need to find a subsequence `a_i,...,a_j` such that `min(S-(a_i+...+a_j),a_i+...+a_j)` is the largest possible (both sums must be non-empty).

Example:

`1,2,3,4,5` the sequence is `3,4`, because then `min(S-(a_i+...+a_j),a_i+...+a_j)=min(8,7)=7` (and it's the largest possible which can be checked for other subsequences).

I tried to do this the hard way.

I load all values into the array `tab[n]`.

I do this `n-1` times `tab[i]+=tab[i-j]`. So that `tab[j]` is the sum from the beginning till `j`.

I check all possible sums `a_i+...+a_j=tab[j]-tab[i-1]`  and substract it from the sum, take the minimum and see if it's larger than before.

It takes `O(n^2)`. This makes me very sad and miserable. Is there a better way?

Comment: Can the numbers be negative?

Comment: No, all are positive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like this can be done in O(n) time.

1. Compute the sum `S`. The ideal subsequence sum is the longest one which gets closest to `S/2`.
2. Start with `i=j=0` and increase `j` until `sum(a_i..a_j)` and `sum(a_i..a_{j+1})` are as close as possible to S/2. Note which ever is closer and save the values of `i_best,j_best,sum_best`.
3. Increment `i` and then increase `j` again until `sum(a_i..a_j)` and `sum(a_i..a_{j+1})` are as close as possible to S/2. Note which ever is closer and replace the values of `i_best,j_best,sum_best` if they are better. Repeat this step until done.

Note that both `i` and `j` are never decremented, so they are changed a total of at most O(n) times. Since all other operations take only constant time, this results in an O(n) runtime for the entire algorithm.

Comment: Some steps may take up to O(n) operations, but total time is O(n) :-)

Comment: @Egor: I added this into the answer

Comment: @NiklasB. You changed this to "This is O(n) because at each step, you are only incrementing i and j" - this is not true; the algorithm is taking additional steps each time `i` and `j` are incremented, but these additional steps are done in O(1). This meaning is lost in your edit. If you can still preserve my original intention with your clarification, that would be great, otherwise I'll be editing this later on today.

Comment: @Matt: Well maybe it's a bad formulation. What I meant is emphasis on "increment", like in "you are only *incrementing* i and j, not decrementing them". Let me try and find a better formulation.

Answer (score 1):

Let's first do some clarifications.

1. A [subsequence](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Subsequence.html) of a sequence is actually a  *subset*  of the indices of the sequence. Haivng said that, and specifically int he case where you sequence has distinct elements, your problem will  *reduce*  to the famous [Partition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem) problem, which is known to be NP-complete. If that is the case, you can manage to solve the problem in O(Sn) where "n" is the number of elements and "S" is the total sum. This is not polynomial time as "S" can be arbitrarily large.
2. So lets consider the case with a contiguous subsequence. You need to observe array elements twice. First run sums them up into some "S". In the second run you carefully adjust array length. Lets assume you know that a[i] + a[i + 1] + ... + a[j] > S / 2. Then you let i = i + 1 to reduce the sum. Conversely, if it was smaller, you would increase j.

This code runs in O(n).

Python code:

```
    from math import fabs
    a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    i = 0
    j = 0
    S = sum(a)
    s = 0
    while s + a[j] <= S / 2:
        s = s + a[j]    
        j = j + 1
    s = s + a[j]


    best_case = (i, j)
    best_difference = fabs(S / 2 - s)
    while True:    
        if fabs(S / 2 - s) < best_difference:
            best_case = (i, j)
            best_difference = fabs(S / 2 - s)
        if s > S / 2:
            s -= a[i]
            i += 1        
        else:
            j += 1
            if j == len(a):
                break
            s += a[j]

    print best_case
    i = best_case[0]
    j = best_case[1]
    print "Best subarray = ", a[i:j + 1]
    print "Best sum = " , sum(a[i:j + 1])
```

Comment: OP talks about "continuous" sum and "a_i, a_{i+1}, ..., a_j", so I guess the question is really about substrings rather than subsequences

Comment: I guess that too. Otherwise, the term "subset" would have been a better option.